# android-how to get a color, make that transparent and then return it?

Tags: java, android, colors, transparent

I want to make a method that takes a color as input, makes it 50 percent transparent and returns it.(for example #FFFFFF as input and #50FFFFFF as output). how to do that?

Comment: @BackSlash I searched to find an start point but didn't find any thing...I'm completely confused

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html has methods to extract the alpha channel, build colors from components, ... `argb(alpha() / 2, red(), green(), blue())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A color in android simply is an integer with ARGB values.

```
public int setAlpha(int color, int alpha) {
    return (alpha << 24) | (color & 0x00ffffff);
}
```

If you prefer to specify the alpha in percentage, rather than on a scale from 0 to 255, you could do

```
public int setAlpha(int color, int alphaPercentage) {
    int alpha = alphaPercentage * 255 / 100;
    return (alpha << 24) | (color & 0x00ffffff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be my solution is bit boring.. But I can suggest something..

Color code are hexadecimals,So convert it to decimals.

Divide decimal by 2 & again convert back result to hexadecimal.

Example :- FFFFFF = 16777215/2 = 8388607 = 7FFFFF..

Comment: `FFFFFFFF` is the only number for which this works. For instance, try `FF808080`. It results in `7FC040404`.